# What's the proper way to safely run this error-prone system call in perl?

Tags: perl, macos, error-handling

So as part of a startup script for OS X computer lab systems, I am running a built-in shell command called systemsetup to sync the system with a network time server. It's running inside a perl script as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system("systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off");
system("systemsetup -setusingnetworktime on");
```

Flipping it to off first ensures that it updates when it is flipped on.

The problem is that every so often, that command throws the following error `writeconfig[1841:903] *** -[NSMachPort handlePortMessage:]: dropping incoming DO message because the connection or ports are invalid` and then stalls either the shell or the script's execution depending on where I'm running it.

This actually happens shockingly little in practice—on 500 lab systems running the script daily at boot, I only notice a problem on a single system every few weeks. Strangely,  it's actually very easy to replicate in testing.

So what I understand is that this is fairly obviously a bug in systemsetup that that error is being thrown, but I'm sure there's a way to make my perl script handle it gracefully, right?

The best thing I've come up with at the moment is `systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off&>/dev/null` which pipes both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null.

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with letting the system automatically sync itself with a network time server?

Comment: I'm sure it would eventually, but at boot time I need to compare a recorded timestamp with the present, and 500 computers means 500 PRAM batteries which may or may not die between now and the end of the machine's lifecycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a command might go haywire and hang your script, a good defense is to use [`alarm`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#alarm) and a `SIGALRM` handler to make the command time out.

```
sub system_with_timeout {
    my ($timeout, @command) = @_;
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" };
    my $result;
    if ($timeout > 0) { alarm $timeout; }
    eval {
        $result = system(@command);
    };
    if ($@ =~ /Timeout/) {
        warn "@command timed out.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Check the return values to make sure your command was successful or whether it timed out.

```
my $z = system_with_timeout(30, "systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off");
if ($z == 0) {
    # success ...
} elsif ($z == -1) {
    # timed out ... try it again ?
} else {
    # failed for some other reason ...
}
```

Comment: rule - i added extra suggestion in my answer in case `systemsetup` does not actually signal errors via return code, which sadly happens fairly often

Comment: @DVK - Indeed; that appears to be true in this case.

Comment: I would recommend returning `undef` on timeout (kind of a grade "Incomplete"). `system` will always return a value. Using -1 causes a collision with programs that return -1. Since this is an error situation, you want the best error reporting possible.

Comment: @DVK Good suggestion. It is straightforward to implement `backticks_with_timeout` or `open-|_with_timeout` functions with the same features.  @Axeman - `system` returns 0 on success. I'd hate to execute the wrong code because I checked if `$returnval == 0` and forgot to check if `defined $retval` when I changed a `system` to a `system_with_timeout` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the error itself (e.g. it is just a warning message), by all means re-direct the STDOUT/STDERR of the command; although I'd personally recommend re-directing to a /tmp logfile (and not `/dev/null`) in case you ever need to troubleshoot some OTHER error.

If you actually wish to take a specific action upon such an error, you can either check the return code (see mobrule's answer), or if the command always returns 0, capture the putput and filter it  for error:

```
my @script_out = `systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off`;
# better yet use open with a pipe instead of backticks 
if (grep {/writeconfig.*dropping incoming DO message/} @script_out {
    # do error handling
}
```